# Deleting by index number openpyxl

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

I am attempting to compare a column of values in two separate sheets from two different workbooks. The first workbook has a single sheet with just the one column of numbers. Firstly I've appended the entire column into a list.

If the numbers in the secondary workbook sheet1 row[3] values match the list values they are kept - otherwise their index number is appended into a new list. This list is then reversed and the rows deleted. This way only the numbers in list 1 remains in workbook2.

List 1 append all the values correctly, however all but one number (always) does not get deleted even though its not found in list 1.

```
Wb2 = load_workbook("workbook2.xlsx") # has a larger amount of numbers that need to be compared to a list an deleted if not appearing in it.
sheet = Wb2.active 

sheet= Wb2["Sheet1"]

Wb1 = load_workbook("workbook.xlsx") # has a single column.
sheet2 = Wb1.active 

sheet2.active = Wb1['Sheet1']

list1 = [] 

#put the sheet2 column 1 into a list to compare
for row in sheet2.iter_rows(1,sheet2.max_row-0):
    #append the list
    list1.append(row[0].)value

#print(list1)
print(len(list1)) #shows the correct len

list2 =[]

for row in sheet1.iter_rows(2,sheet1.max_row-1): #has a header
    if row[3].value not in list1:
        list2.append(row[0].row)
    else:
        print(row[3].value, "is in the list")
        
#print(list2) #these are the rows which will be deleted


for row_idx in reversed(list2): #to avoid the index from shifting-up, indexed
    sheet8.delete_rows(row_idx)
```

Answer (score 0):

For what I understood, maybe [pop()](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/pop) will work

```
for row in sheet1.iter_rows(2,sheet1.max_row-1): #has a header
    if row[3].value not in list1:
        list2=list1.pop(row[0].row)
    else:
        print(row[3].value, "is in the list")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).